# Visual Studio Professional 2013 32-bit versus 32-bit web installer

Tags: 32-bit

When downloading Visual Studio Professional 2013, you have the option of downloading 32-bit and 32-bit web installer. What's the difference?

Answer (score 0):

The web installer installs a small stub that then downloads the rest of the program. So you end up with Visual Studio installed but not a installer file (so nothing you could copy to another machine to install).
The web installer though may be quicker as it only downloads what you need based on your selection